# Как заменить breadcrumb из дочерней темы?

Tags: php, wordpress

В основной теме, не дочерней, в файле `functions.php` используется код для вывода хлебных крошек без использования хуков, примерно так:

**functions.php - основная тема**

```
function page_breadcrumb(){
//код вывода хл. крошек
...
}
```

**/themes/theme-name/index.php**

```
//шаблон темы
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
...
page_breadcrumb()
...
</div>
get_footer();
```

и в файле `index.php`, который лежит в корне темы, выводятся эти хл. крошки.
Я так понял если в основной теме нет хуков для хл-х крошек, то в дочерней теме нельзя будет переопределить этот код хл. крошек?
Нужно будет менять хл. крошки в основной теме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопируйте код функции `page_breadcrumb()` в дочернюю тему, переименуйте функцию в, скажем, `my_page_breadcrumb()`, внесите в неё нужные изменения.

Скопируйте файл index.php в дочернюю тему. Замените в нём вызов `page_breadcrumb()` на `my_page_breadcrumb()`.

Comment: я так уже делал, не сработало, т.е. хл. крошки выводятся из основной темы

Comment: Вы делали не так, потому что так - сработает. Какие крошки из основной темы, если вы в index.php вы меняете название вызываемой функции?

Comment: в том то и дело, что из дочерней темы скорее всего не срабатывает файл `index.php`, потому-что в дочерней теме я по другому назвал функцию хл. крошек и там другой контент тестовый. Проделал такое же на стандартной теме `twentynineteen`. Создал дочернюю тему `twentynineteen-child` и в файл `index.php` добавил изменённую версию файла `index.php` из основной темы, но из дочерней темы файл `index.php` не срабатывает

Comment: Значит, у вас функция вызывается не из index.php (не только из index.php).